# Kohana Framework: Is it possible to insert a loading page?

Tags: loading, kohana-3

I have a Controller that does heavy work that takes some time to do.

Is it possible to insert a loading page while waiting for the Controller to solve?

If I put the loading page in the View, then the loading page will be displayed after the Controller is solved, which beats the purpose.

Comment: Maybe you could init the controller before event and revoke it in the after event? You could create a view and call as a HMVC request there.

Comment: From my understanding, this is how Kohana would draw the components: { Controller + all the Hierarchy for parents } made into a View, then send the whole page to client. The loader part would be too late since it will be a part of the View anyway, not before controller processing anything.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution without hacking Kohana to bits would be to send the request to the controller via AJAX, and have a jQuery preloading gif/animation whilst it's waiting for the response. You could return the generated content (the view) as JSON data and then output it wherever you like.

If you've not used AJAX before, it is pretty easy to learn the basics. See http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ for a quick tutorial.

We use this technique a lot when loading large amounts of data, and for pagination so the page doesn't have to reload.

Comment: The reason I'm looking for a way to do this on the framework level is so that I can solve this problem by just changing the top parent classes. Not prefer to adjust every line of code that links to another link. I was hoping that there is some parts of Kohana that are just awaiting to be activated.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this safely. You could probably do it by picking apart some of the system files, but then upgrading it would be a nightmare. Good luck finding a solution.